# Email sending with perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl script which sends a mail to the developer to show the status i.e. fail or pass to developer email id. I also want to get the such status mail when I am using the script. So,I tried as below ,

TO: 'developer@abc.com , $userid@abc.com'. But in this case developer is getting the mnailbut I am still not getting it. can you Please help here?
I am new to Perl and so it may be possible that my question is not upto the stanard.But please help,I need it urgently.

Thanks & regards,
Gautam

Comment: Unless people know more details no-one can help. How are you setting this? What does the script expect? How have you checked this?

Answer (score 5):

you are interpolating a variable into a single quoted string. Perl assumes everything in single quotes should be taken literally..

example:

```
my $userid = 'admin';
my $string = '$userid@abc.com';
print $string;
```

results in "$userid@abc.com"

However, if you substitute double quotes in the second line

```
my $string = "$userid\@abc.com";
```

results in "admin@abc.com"

So if you want to interpolate a variable use double quotes:

```
"developer\@abc.com , $userid\@abc.com"
```

Comment: With double quotes, you also need to escape the `@`: "$userid\@abc.com"